# Looping over Ruby hash and accessing values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am quite new to Ruby and could not find an appropriate answer to my questions. Let's say I have hash named 
    `users_hsh = {}`.
I am looping through all of my users in the DB and creating the following.

```
users.each do |user|
     users_hsh[user.full_name] = {
         completed_activities: some_integer_value,
         active_activities: some_integer_value,
         future_activities: some_integer_value
     } 
end
```

Now, I created a new hash named
    `total_sum_not_zero_user_hsh = {}`.
I want to loop over all of the users in the users_hsh and check for each user if the total sum of completed_activities + active_activities + future_activities does not equal 0 and if this condition holds, I want to add this user to total_sum_not_zero_user_hsh. I have done the following but seems that this does not work.

```
users_hsh.each do |usr|
    if usr.values.sum != 0
        total_sum_not_zero_user_hsh[usr] = {
            completed_activities: some_integer_value,
            active_activities: some_integer_value,
            future_activities: some_integer_value
        }
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the values in users_hsh. Just the format of values would be enough.

Comment: Sure, an example users_hsh["Elvin Jafarli"] = {completed_activities: 10, active_activities: 2, future_activities: 0}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use your example of:

```
users_hash = {
  "Elvin Jafarli" => {
    completed_activities: 10,
    active_activities: 2,
    future_activities: 0
  }
}
```

Think carefully about what your data structure actually is: It's a hash that maps the user name to some user attributes. If you loop through these values, you don't just get a `usr`, you get back precisely this mapping.

It's helpful to name your variables descriptively:

```
users_hsh.each do |user_name, user_attributes|
  if user_attributes.values.sum != 0
    # ...
  end
end
```

With your attempt, you would have seen an error like this: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'values' for #<Array:0x00007fe14e22f538>`. What happened is that each `usr` was actually an `Array` such as:

```
["Elvin Jafarli", {completed_activities: 10, active_activities: 2, future_activities: 0}]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: I would advise using a tool such as [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) to put breakpoints in your code and debug issue like this. Inspect the variables at the point of failure.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering how to debug in ruby. Thanks again!